# In beamer, list only current subsections of current section

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

If the stucture of the table of contents is something like this

Section1

- subsection1.1
- subsection1.2

Section2

- subsection2.1
- subsection2.2

Section3

- subsection3.1
- subsection3.2

I would like to see at the first frame of a section the following "local" table of contents

no-----Section1 and subsections

Section2 (maybe only in frametitle)

- subsection2.1 (maybe subsubsections)
- subsection2.2

no-----Section3 and subsections

So, WITHOUT other sections even shaded. Is it possible? (Too many (sub)sections in a semester...)

Comment: Does `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` help you? See full intro of `\tableofcontents` used in `beamer` in its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), sec. 10.5.

Comment: Arter 2 hours of trying it succeeded. I think it isn't explained properly in the docs. thx bytheway!

Comment: You can post your final solution as an answer. This will help others in the future, and can make this question having an accepted answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.